# Cosa significa "disciogliere" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Dapprima non ci furono parole, ma, nello sguardo d'Orazio, quella luce gioviale di quando discorreva di pittura o gliene mostravano, specchio di una attività desiderosa e felice. Erano anni che la figliola non la ritrovava e fu un raggio di sole che le distese la mano chiusa sul lapis, illuminò il foglio, *disciolse* le sue membra umiliate.

È chiaro che l'autrice fa un uso figurato del verbo "disciogliere", associato probabilmente a un certo senso di liberazione ([accezione **1** del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/disciogliere)). Tuttavia, non capisco molto bene qual è il significato di "disciogliere le membra umiliate" nel brano precedente. Rilassare le membra in tensione? Liberare del senso di colpa e dell'umiliazione?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non ricordo la parte precedente al brano che citi. Mi sembra che qui l'immagine usata da Anna Banti cominci da "fu un raggio di sole". Immagina un paesaggio invernale, un campo coperto di neve che, appena il sole comincia a scaldare di più l'aria, si scioglie e torna a muoversi, dopo una lunga immobilità. Questo l'effetto dello sguardo di Orazio: un calore che fa dimenticare una dolorosa e tesa immobilità.

Comment: Puoi trovarlo qui: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Banti#Artemisia_.281947.29.

Comment: Capisco: non avevo pensato al raggio di sole che discioglie la neve.